# Init + private set accessors on the same property?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Is it possible to use a public init accessor and a private setter on the same property?

Currently I get error [CS1007](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1007) "Property accessor already defined".

```cs
public record Stuff
{
    public int MyProperty { get; init; private set; } // Error

    public void SetMyProperty(int value) => MyProperty = value;
}

var stuff = new Stuff
{
    MyProperty = 3, // Using the init accessor
};

stuff.SetMyProperty(4); // Using the private setter (indirectly)
```

My best guess would be to use a private member variable, a property for that variable with `get` and `init` accessors (not auto-implemented) and the setter member function. Can it be done more easily?

Comment: What's the point of this? You're trying to specify the setter twice. `init` is a setter too

Comment: It's not possible, no. The `init` accessor uses the same `set_MyProperty` set method as a `set` accessor: it's just decorated with a `modreq`.

Comment: The whole idea of `init` is to make the property immutable. Having a setter defeats that purpose

Comment: The goal is to have "mostly immutable" objects, where the thumb rule is immutability but there are a few well defined exceptions. We can use `with`, but that does not make any logic (e.g. consistency checks) possible.

Comment: I guess the best solution I could suggest for that would be to use a private setter and set the initial value through a constructor.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Similar to specifying a constructor to initialize your value, you can use a private backing field so that you can still take advantage of the init logic and allow initialization without a specific constructor

```cs
public record Stuff
{
    private int _myProperty;

    public int MyProperty { get => _myProperty; init => _myProperty = value; }

    public void SetMyProperty(int value) => _myProperty = value;
}

var stuff = new Stuff
{
    MyProperty = 3 // Using the init accessor
};

stuff.SetMyProperty(4); // Using the private setter (indirectly)
```

Answer (score 7):

No you can not. The init keyword was added in an attempt to make immutable properties on objects.

So if you have the record:

```
public record Stuff
{
    public int MyProperty { get; init; } // This can not be changed after initialization
}
```

`MyProperty` can only be set during the initialization of your record.

If you want your property to be mutable then you use the `set` accessor **instead** of `init`.

```
public record Stuff
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; } // This can
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hasan, I did mean set

Answer (score 2):

As @Jerry's answer you can not use both setters. That is to do with the mutability of the record/object.

If you want to have `private set`ers and some initialization logic also, the way I use is constructors:

```
public record Stuff
{
    public Stuff(int myProperty)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty;
    }

    public int MyProperty { get; private set; }

    public void SetMyProperty(int value) => MyProperty = value;
}

var stuff = new Stuff(3);
stuff.SetMyProperty(4);
```

It is all about domain requirements.

- Does `Stuff.MyProperty` needs to be publicly modifiable?
- If it is, what would be the default value of that property, when Stuff instance is initialized? Does domain expects a default value?

etc..

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a record with multiple properties and wish to change the accessibility of the setter for only a few of them, you can use the following syntax:

```cs
public sealed record Stuff(int MyProperty, string ImutableProperty, DateTimeOffset AnotherProperty)
{
    public int MyProperty { get; private set; } = MyProperty;   
    public DateTimeOffset AnotherProperty { get; set; } = AnotherProperty;
        
    public void SetMyProperty(int value) => MyProperty = value;
}
```

In this code, `MyProperty` has a private setter, so it can only be set within the class, `AnotherProperty` has a public setter, allowing it to be set from external code. Additionally all properties are required to be initialized.

[dotnet fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BifbUw)