# How to combine property init and set depending on access modifier?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I want a class/record with protected set and public init access restriction?
To my knowledge this even cannot be done by explicitly implementing a "Set" interface like this:

```
    public interface ISetData<T>
    {
        T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data : ISetData<bool>
    {
        bool ISetData<bool>.Value { get => Value; set => Value = value; } // Error The property Value has no setter

        public bool Value { get; init; }
    }
```

Downside is, set functionality is public when using the interface. Not good. (for internal components the interface can be made internal, but that's mostly no option)
Given that only derivations of Data should be able to set data after initialization, the only solution I see is to use an backing field for the property, which is annoying.

Which looks like:

```
    public interface ISetData<T>
    {
        T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data : ISetData<bool>
    {
        bool ISetData<bool>.Value { get => Value; set => _value = value; } // Fine

        private bool _value;

        public bool Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            init { }
        }
    }
```

That seems odd to me. Would it not be better CLR/c# allows to use access modifiers independently of set/init this like:

```
    public class Data
    {
        public bool Value { get; init; protected set; }
    }
```

I know this would better be addressed by a feature request, but this is not what this post is about.

So what solutions are available for the scenario "public init, but protected set"?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783995/init-private-set-accessors-on-the-same-property#64783995

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer is **none**.

In C# 9.0, you could have either `init` or `protected set`, not both.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a separate property that is protected set and then the public property can be based on your protected property. Example below.

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var example = new Example{Test = "hello world"};
        example.PrintProtectedTest();
        Console.WriteLine(example.Test);
        example.SetProtectedTest("goodbye world");
        Console.WriteLine(example.Test);
    }
}

class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
    }

    protected string ProtectedTest { get; set; }

    public string Test
    {
        get => ProtectedTest;
        init => ProtectedTest = value;
    }

    public void SetProtectedTest(string test)
    {
        ProtectedTest = test;
    }

    public void PrintProtectedTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ProtectedTest);
    }
}
```

You can run the example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/odGwDj

Comment: Sorry, realizing now this is just a slight variation of using a backing field like you were describing and may not add much.