# Is there a way to use different accessibility modifier for a setter in C#11 when using the "required" keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

Is there a way to use different accessibility modifier for a setter in C#11 when using the "required" keyword?

```cs
    public class Person
    {
        
        public required string FirstName { get; protected set; }

        public void ChangeNameToMike()
        {
            FirstName = "Mike";
        }
    }
```

What I would like to achieve, is that when you instantiate the Person class, you'd need to provide a "FirstName" and you can access the name anywhere, but modifying it should only be possible inside the class and classes that inherit from the Person class. I know that it's possible to achieve this via a constructor, but would like to achieve it with the new required keyword, or something similar, basically to use newer way to write C# code.

The exact error I'm getting is:
CS9032 Required member 'Person.FirstName' cannot be less visible or have a setter less visible than the containing type 'Person'.

It works with a constructor, but I wanted to achieve the same result without one.

```cs
    public class Person
    {
        
        public string FirstName { get; protected set; }

        public Person(string firstName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
        }

        public void ChangeNameToMike()
        {
            FirstName = "Mike";
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're initializing it in the constructor, you don't need `required`. The point of `required` is that the consumer is required to set it in the object initializer, which they can't do if the setter is less accessible than the type.

Comment: I actually find this behaviour a little obnoxious.  Having a required property with an internal setter would be a way to allow consumers outside your assembly to use the type but prevent them from creating or modifying instances of it.  And it would be more efficient than the alternatives (abstract base class or interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64810951/5133585), you can add a protected *field*, and implement the public `get` and `init` accessors explicitly.

```
public class Person
{
    protected string firstName = "";
    public required string FirstName {
        get => firstName;
        init => firstName = value;
    }

    public void ChangeNameToMike()
    {
        firstName = "Mike";
    }
}
```

Since the property has a public `init` accessor, the compiler is happy about the `required` modifier, and you can set the *field* when you want to set it.

Comment: Thank you! To be honest I don't really like how the code looks as a result of this, but I guess there's no better solution at the moment.